# Recursively validating HTML input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I have written the following recursive input validator and it works for me. Is there a better way to visit each dom element and check if it is an input field and validate it?

```
function formValidator(parent)
{
    //base case no children
    if( parent.children().length == 0)
        return

    //recurse through each childs' child
    parent.children().each(function(){
        formValidator($(this));

    /**
    * Work : check if this node is an input node
    */
        if($(this).is("input"))
        {
            var type = $(this).attr('type');

            if(type =="text")
              //do work bro

        }

   });//end for each

}
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for [the code review stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) since the nature of your question is to seek improvement rather than help with a problem.

Comment: Oh my, I didn't even know code review was a thing. Can I move my post there or can someone move it for me?

Comment: You can delete your post here and repost it there (preferred), or flag it for a moderator's attention, asking for it to be migrated (probably avoid that as it's more work for the overworked moderators). — now you have an answer I don't think you **can** delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by better you mean less verbose, this is equivalent functionally

```
parent.find('*').each(function(){
    /**
    * Work : check if this node is an input node
    */
        if($(this).is("input"))
        {
            var type = $(this).attr('type');

            if(type =="text")
              //do work bro

        }

   });//end for each
```

Notice that there is no need for recursion here because

```
parent.find('*')
```

uses the [*(all-selector)](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/). This will get all children and nested children.

**Update**

To improve performance, you can refactor above to

```
parent.find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        var type = $(this).attr('type');

                //if(type =="text")
                  //above no longer needed
       });//end for each
```

This will get all nested `input` elements so you won't have to even check for

```
if($(this).is("input"))
```

Comment: I like this answer but I'm mildly curious which would be more efficient.

Comment: You can avoid the `type` check with `parent.find('input:text') ...`

Comment: @RickHitchcock, very nice observation! Updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use a narrower selector:

```
parent.children().find("input:text").each(function(){
    // Valid $(this) element to validate
});
```

Comment: This excludes inputs that are immediate children of `parent`, which the OP's code handles (`if($(this).is("input"))`).  You can fix it by removing the `children()` method.